# How to set Jenkins JDK/Environment before deployment?

Tags: java, groovy, jenkins

we want to provide an auto-installer for my company. So that the developers do not have to set up their workbench with a very long installation guide.
We managed to provide 90%.

Last week we received an email that we should configure Jenkins during the installation. 
The first part of configuring the Proxy Setting is via a groovy script.

**Groovy file:**

```
pc = new hudson.ProxyConfiguration(name, port, userName, password, noProxyHost);
jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.proxy = pc;
println "Jenkins-Proxy settings updated!
```

**Commandline**

```
type set setJenkinsProxy.groovy | java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s 
http://localhost:8080/jenkins groovy =
```

The next part is to set the already installed JDK.
First thought was to use a groovy script to set the JDK.

**Groovy file:**

```
jdk = new hudson.model.JDK(name, home, list);
jdklist = []
jdklist.add(jdk)
jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.JDKs = jdk;
println "JDK settings updated!
```

Even with a runnable .jar file, that will use the jenkins-cli.jar, it didn't work.

**JDK.jar**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

            JDK jdk = new JDK(args[0], args[1]);

            List<JDK> jdklist = new ArrayList<JDK>();
            jdklist.add(jdk);
            jenkins.model.Jenkins.jdks = jdklist;

            System.out.println("Jenkins JDK set!");

        }
```

Is there a proper way to set this Environment? I would really appreciate any way of help.

EDIT:
Would like to set Jenkins Location as well as Email- Notification too.

Comment: why would each developer need to set their own instance of Jenkins ? I don't understand.

Comment: The answer, so far I heard, was for testing. 
Is there a solution doing this during or alternatively after the installation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found something to set the LocationConfiguration in Jenkins after the installation. 
So if anyone need it, this is the groovy script executable with jenkins-cli.jar

```
liste = new File('filename to read from').readLines()

jlc = new jenkins.model.JenkinsLocationConfiguration();
println jlc.getUrl()
println jlc.getAdminAddress()
jlc.setUrl("http://" + liste[0] + ":8080/jenkins/");
jlc.setAdminAddress(liste[1]);

println ("Set url to: http://" + liste[0] + ":8080/jenkins/")
println ("Set AdminAddress to: " + liste[1])
println "JenkinsLocation updated!"
```

Answer (score 2):

and here the example to set the jdk (groovy script executing via commandline)

```
name = "Java";
home = "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.7.0_40";
list = null;

dis = new hudson.model.JDK.DescriptorImpl();
dis.setInstallations( new hudson.model.JDK(name, home));

println "JDK settings updated!"
```

Answer (score 2):

I came across this question while trying to get the same thing to work with Jenkins' `init.groovy.d` scripts. I was able to get it auto-installing the JDK with the following script:

```
import jenkins.model.*
import hudson.model.*
import hudson.tools.*

def inst = Jenkins.getInstance()

def desc = inst.getDescriptor("hudson.model.JDK")

def versions = [
  "jdk8": "jdk-8u102-oth-JPR"
]
def installations = [];

for (v in versions) {
  def installer = new JDKInstaller(v.value, true)
  def installerProps = new InstallSourceProperty([installer])
  def installation = new JDK(v.key, "", [installerProps])
  installations.push(installation)
}

desc.setInstallations(installations.toArray(new JDK[0]))

desc.save()  
// Required: enter credentials at http://l:8080/descriptorByName/hudson.tools.JDKInstaller/enterCredential
```

Comment: Just to add to this, you now also need to install the jdk-tool plug-in, as without it JDKInstaller is undefined. Seems this was split out of the main code into a plug-in.

Answer (score 1):

@jason-miller Thanks for that.  However I found I needed to add `inst.save()` or the installations were not saved to config.xml (and so not permanent).

I have a slightly different application.  I wanted to point to existing JDK installations in /usr/java so I modified your code as follows:

```
#!groovy
// On GUI, this is on Configure Tools page, "JDK" section
// In config.xml, this is under <jdks>

import jenkins.model.*
import hudson.model.*
import groovy.io.FileType

def jdkDir = "/usr/java"
def inst = Jenkins.getInstance()
def desc = inst.getDescriptor("hudson.model.JDK")

def dirs = []
def currentDir = new File(jdkDir)
currentDir.eachFile FileType.DIRECTORIES, {
    dirs << it.name
}

def installations = []
for (dir in dirs) {
  def installation = new JDK(dir, jdkDir + "/" + dir)
  installations.push(installation)
}

desc.setInstallations(installations.toArray(new JDK[0]))

desc.save()
inst.save()
```